# Assigning Folder permissions within a FTP site on IIS

Tags: permissions, ftp, iis-7

Hi I am novice in FTP setup but I have a single FTP site with several folder structure and many files I was given to maintain on a IIS 7 server. The question I have how do I assign permission? Currently all users who sign in to this FTP site can see and read all the folders and its contents. I want to be able to assign some users to only read and write to certain folders in that FTP location.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, IIS ftp only contains the FTP isolate feature which contains the setting to isolate FTP user sessions to the physical directory with the same name of the FTP user account.

The user sees only their FTP root location and is, therefore, restricted from navigating higher up the physical directory tree. Any global virtual directories that are created will apply to all users.

If this match your requirement, you could refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/iis/publish/using-the-ftp-service/configure-ftp-with-iis-manager-authentication-in-iis-7) to know how to set the ftp isolate.

Besides, if you used other FTP auth mode like management auth or windows auth , I suggest you could consider modify the folder permission in folder property's security for each special user.

Answer (score 0):

By using FTP Authorization rules it is possible to set specific rights for specific users on folders.
This is quite tedious work, as each permission is inherited from the folder above. So starting from the root you need to add permissions for each folder.

For each folder you need to:

- Add a read permission to a folder for all users that needs to access this folder OR underlying folders. This permission is needed to be able to access subfolders.
- Add a read and write permission to the folder for all users that need to read and write in the folder.
- REMOVE permissions that are inherited from top folders that is not correct for this folder.

This is all done within IIS-manager, by clicking a folder in the lefthand menu and then clicking the FTP Authorization rules, and setting the permissions there.